# Can I travel from Kiev to Busan on train?

Tags: visas, trains

Is there any site where I can see ticket prices for all legs(?)?
What about visas?
Will it be cheaper than flying?
I heard about this new China-Europe rail route.

Comment: [*Be careful on the train to Busan*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt5700672/) ;-)

Comment: Welcome to TSE. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help], as Stack Exchange is somewhat particular about how questions should be put. For example, you should indicate what research effort you have already put in, and ask only one question at a time. The short answer is no. You cannot cross from North Korea to South Korea by train, nor indeed by any other mode; you must transit via a third country such as China or Japan.

Comment: The China to Europe rail route that I heard about was freight-only.

Comment: My original question can be reworded as: "Hey, I've just realized that traveling can be almost twice as cheaper as I've researched two years ago with the help of a different web site. Should I fly for ~$580-640 to Narita/Haneda and back or use a train/ferry/some new line with a limited budget?" I would never get a response that I needed to start researching further, I would be limited only to sites that I knew without asking here first.

Comment: Now I know, that only ferry from Shanghai to Korea (and back) will cost around $240-260 from Shanghai to Osaka - starting from 300+. So I don't believe that it will be cheaper than flying.

Comment: I don't know why I've written this. Excuse me.

Comment: Kiev-Vladivostok - starting from $250, 
Vladivostok-Donghae: 
£315.84, 
Donghae - Sakaiminato: 
£258.21,

"The Vladivostok - Sakaiminato route is no longer running and there are currently no direct alternative ferry services between Russia and Japan either".
+ cost of several visas, I suppose, (need to research). Now I see that this one of the available routes is very expensive. But I have zero Idea about new Silk route Chinese line.

Comment: Actually, Shanghai to Osaka (and back) - $316

Comment: I am wrong about "ferry from Shanghai to Korea". Can't find the route.

Comment: @JohnSmith The point of taking the train from Europe to Korea should be adventure and sightseeing, not cost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take a train to the east coast of Russia (Vladivostok) or China, then [take a ferry to South Korea](https://www.seat61.com/SouthKorea.htm#Travel%20to%20South%20Korea).

The overland route is blocked by the lack of trains (or, indeed, any ways to cross) between North Korea and South Korea.

Visas depend on your nationality.  From Kiev you can skip Belarus but most Europeans would need visas for both Russia and China.

Comment: Not only by the lack of trains but also by the lack of *any* border crossing over the DMZ that does not require you to go right back.

Comment: @Jan True, although [someone *did* cross](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2017/nov/13/soldier-shot-by-north-korean-guards-as-he-defects-to-south) it's not currently recommended…

Comment: @Coke I'm confused.  What is off-topic and why?  This question and answer seem very much on-topic for this site, but probably I misunderstand what you're trying to say.

Comment: @Gerrit No, it's just my brain that's tired and thought of something else